# Return an arbitrary Encodable from a match expression?

Tags: serialization, rust

I have a match expression than can return several (builtin and custom) types, which will ultimately be serialized to JSON and returned from a web request.  I would prefer to avoid repeating the serialization code or making a string copy in each match arm.

Each arm returns an `Encodable`; however, it seems that `Encodable` is not object-safe, so I cannot make a pointer to it.

**Edit**: Due to changes in Rust, the question has gone from "Is this a good way to do this?" to "How can I do this at all?"  (This is with version `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (ed530d7a3 2015-01-16 22:41:16 +0000)`)

```
extern crate "rustc-serialize" as rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::{json, Encodable};

#[derive(RustcEncodable)]
struct Valid {
    value: u32
}

#[derive(RustcEncodable)]
struct Error {
    error: &'static str // '
}

fn main() {
    let valid = true;
    let result = match valid {
        true => Box::new(Valid { value: 42 }) as Box<Encodable>,
        false => Box::new(Error { error: "bork" }) as Box<Encodable>
    };
    let mut buf = String::new();
    result.encode(&mut json::Encoder::new(&mut buf)).unwrap();
    println!("{}", buf);
}
```

`` error: cannot convert to a trait object because trait `rustc-serialize::serialize::Encodable` is not object-safe [E0038] ``

Comment: `match x { true => y, false => z }` is precisely equivalent to `if x { y } else { z }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways in which traits can be used in Rust:

1. As bounds in generic functions (static dispatch)
2. As trait objects, behind pointers (dynamic dispatch)

Because `Encodable` is not object-safe, we can't use dynamic dispatch, because the compiler doesn't allow us to create a pointer to an `Encodable`.

Therefore, we have to use static dispatch. To do this, I've moved the code that works on the `Encodable` to a new, generic function, and called it from each arm.

```
extern crate "rustc-serialize" as rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::{json, Encodable};

#[derive(RustcEncodable)]
struct Valid {
    value: u32
}

#[derive(RustcEncodable)]
struct Error {
    error: &'static str // '
}

fn do_encode<E: Encodable>(e: E) -> () {
    let mut buf = String::new();
    e.encode(&mut json::Encoder::new(&mut buf)).unwrap();
    println!("{}", buf);
}

fn main() {
    let is_valid = true;
    match is_valid {
        true => do_encode(Valid { value: 42 }),
        false => do_encode(Error { error: "bork" }),
    };
}
```

Comment: This is still basically the same thing, just a way of scrapping a heap allocation. I think the question was more about the technique overall of using `Encodable` trait objects.

Comment: Fantastic, I like that that's a pretty general solution for this problem.